# NextJS getInitialProps is not passing how I would expect and I get compiler error "varName not found on type {}"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I think I am having a simple Syntax issue that is roadbloacking me hard on NextJs right now.

I'm trying to do some dynamic server side fetches so I tried to the getInitialProps pattern but the compiler can't recognize the return of getInitialProps in the normal functional component render:

```
interface Props {
    date: string,
    user: number
}


const DayTimeView: NextComponentType<Props> = ({timeRecords, date, user}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>DayTimeView</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

DayTimeView.getInitialProps  = async (props: Props) => {
    let sesh = getSession();
    let timeRecords = []
    getSession().then((session) => {fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/time/date/' +new Date(props.date).toISOString(), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-auth-token": session.user.id},
        })
    .then(res => res.json().then(data => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            timeRecords = data;
        }else{
            timeRecords = []; // Todo default
        }
    }))})
    return {props: { timeRecords: timeRecords, date: props.date, user: props.user }}
    
}

export default DayTimeView;
```

Here is the compiler error:
[image: error]

And it's not the fact timeRecords doesn't exist in props because it doesn't work even when removing timeRecords for the same error on date and user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DayTimeView` should be of type `NextPage`, which is a `NextComponentType` that also includes a NextJS context.

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
const DayTimeView: NextPage<Props> = ...
```

Comment: This is half the answer, the full answer I wanted to use getInitialProps with a functional re-usable React Component and that simply isn't allowed or supported in NextJS (at least the version I am using beta 13 has some kind of functionality for this)